# Featherlight iFrame How to Allow Fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using [Featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) to open an iframe in a popup modal.

You can see a demo if you click the iframe button on the site.

---

How can I make Featherlight add `allowfullscreen="true"` to the generated iframe tag? Videos will not go fullscreen without this parameter.

If you view the source html of the demo you can see that it adds it. But when I download and use `featherlight.min.js` it does not apply that parameter to the tag by default.

---

View Source

**From the demo:**

[image: fullscreen param]

**When used on my site:**

[image: mysite iframe]

---

The [code](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#open-lightbox-with-iframe) for opening an iframe:

```
<a href="/content" data-featherlight="iframe">Open Popup</a>
```

---

I looked for a solution [here](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/issues/73), but I cannot find a section like this in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer was to use `data-featherlight-iframe-allowfullscreen="true"` in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#open-youtube-video-with-featherlight - Just found this, hope it helps someone.